# Running many Selenium tasks concurrently and preventing system crashes

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, asynchronous, async-await, task

I am going to get the population rank of each country from a site by Selenium and HtmlAgilityPack (in C#, .NET 7). This code works well for 10 countries, but when I want to request all the countries, due to many tasks, the system crashes and I encounter slowness. What is the way?

```
static async void GetData()
{
    string website = "......";
    List<string> Countries = new List<string>()
    {
        // 195 Countries
    };

    List<Task<JObject>> Tasks = new List<Task<JObject>>();
    foreach (string countryName in Countries)
    {
        Tasks.Add(FetchData(website + "/" + countryName));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(Tasks);
    foreach (JObject populationRank in Tasks.Select(task => task.Result))
    {
        WriteLine(populationRank);
    }
}

static Task<JObject> FetchData(string URL)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        ChromeDriver myDriver = new CustomizedDriver();
        myDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
        HtmlDocument Document = new HtmlDocument();
        Document.LoadHtml(await myDriver.GetPageSourceAsync());
        JObject Object = new JObject()
        {
            ["PopulationRank"] = Document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='popRank']").InnerText
        };
        myDriver.Quit();
        myDriver.Dispose();
        return Object;
    });
}
static Task<string> GetPageSourceAsync(this IWebDriver driver)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string PageState = (string)( (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver ).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState");
            if (PageState == "interactive" || PageState == "complete")
                return driver.PageSource;
        }
    });
}
static ChromeDriver CustomizedDriver()
{
    ChromeDriverService chromeService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    chromeService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.None;
    options.AddArgument("--headless --disable-cookies --blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false");
    return new ChromeDriver(chromeService, options);
}
```

Comment: Could you include in the question the calling site of the `GetData` method?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I apologize for the delay; Yes, I use .NET 7

This code that I wrote was simply simplified, otherwise the information is different in reality. The site https://countrymeters.info/en was the one I used. You can also get the list of countries from DropDown

Comment: Since you are targeting .NET 7, have you consider using the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) API?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I said in reply to '@sadbuttrue'. This method was responsive, but unfortunately it takes 10 minutes and the system lags a bit. Can this be divided into several threads? Somehow implemented on all CPU cores?

Comment: This is what the `Parallel.ForEach`/`Parallel.ForEachAsync` are supposed to do. If you can't improve the performance with them, by experimenting with the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, then whatever you are doing is inherently not parallelizable.

Comment: As a side note, the [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void "Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming - Avoid Async Void") is intended for event handlers. And the `GetData` doesn't look like an event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn´t create a large amount of tasks all at once. Instead, you should use Parallel.ForEachAsync, like in this example:

```
    static async void GetData()
{
    string website = "......";
    List<string> Countries = new List<string>()
    {
        // 195 Countries
    };

    var results = new ConcurrentBag<JObject>();
    
    var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions()
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 // Here you control how many countries in parallel to process.
    };

    Parallel.ForEachAsync(Countries, parallelOptions, async (country, token) => 
    {
        var result = await FetchData(website + "/" + countryName);
        results.Add(result);
    }

    foreach (JObject populationRank in results))
    {
        WriteLine(populationRank);
    }
}

static async Task<JObject> FetchData(string URL)
{
        ChromeDriver myDriver = new CustomizedDriver();
        myDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
        HtmlDocument Document = new HtmlDocument();
        Document.LoadHtml(await myDriver.GetPageSourceAsync());
        JObject Object = new JObject()
        {
            ["PopulationRank"] = Document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='popRank']").InnerText
        };
        myDriver.Quit();
        myDriver.Dispose();
        return Object;
}
static Task<string> GetPageSourceAsync(this IWebDriver driver)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string PageState = (string)( (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver ).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState");
            if (PageState == "interactive" || PageState == "complete")
                return driver.PageSource;
        }
    });
}
static ChromeDriver CustomizedDriver()
{
    ChromeDriverService chromeService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    chromeService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.None;
    options.AddArgument("--headless --disable-cookies --blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false");
    return new ChromeDriver(chromeService, options);
}
```

Comment: Your method was responsive, but unfortunately it takes 10 minutes and the system lags a bit. Can this be divided into several threads? Somehow implemented on all CPU cores?

Comment: You can increase the amount of threads by incrementing the MaxDegreesOfParalelism variable.